# JavaFx: Could not create player

Tags: java, javafx, java-platform-module-system, javafx-11, jlink

I'm writing a JavaFx application targeting Java 13.
I use gradle with the openjfx plugin to build my project.

Building it this way ,everytime i try to create a mediaplayer i get:

````
MediaException: UNKNOWN : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!```
````

I have all necessary libraries installed including all version of libav 54-58. And i use valid uri format.
I have then tried to use a custom jre that i created by running jlink and add all javafx and standard modules to it.

```
jlink --module-path=/path/to/jmods --add-modules=ALL-MODULE-PATH --output=/path/to/output
```

Now i get this Exception when i start the Application and create the first window. But my test cases with the audio player run successfully.

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumMessagesBundle, locale en_US
```

The last thing i tried was to use an older javafx jre i created with version 12. This version doesn't show any of the 2 problems.
My problem is that i really want to use the javafx modules i get from gradle, because then updating etc. get easier and i want to create a custom runtime for my application later.

Comment: I have run into this same issue (the MissingResourceException) in building the Sample JavaFX project in IntelliJ with java-13-openjdk and java-openjfx (the latest one in pacman targeting Java 13).

Comment: @AlexMcMurray same here. I left a comment [here](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/64225?project=1&string=java-openjfx). My solution currently is to use [openjfx](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/) from gluon

Answer (score 0):

I've also run into this issue with IntelliJ IDEA's Sample JavaFX project, using Java 13.

To work around this problem, I created a file named `QuantumMessagesBundle.properties` with the following contents:

`OverlayWarningESC = Press ESC to exit full-screen mode.`

Then, I opened `/usr/lib/jvm/java-13-openjdk/lib/javafx-graphics.jar` and placed this file at `com/sun/javafx/tk/quantum/QuantumMessagesBundle.properties`.

Comment: This is a valid attempt to answer the question. Please don't flag/vote to delete an answer just because the author says they had the same issue before explaining their workaround or solution.

Comment: Clarification: I ran across this question while trying to solve my own problem. Once I found a solution that worked for me, I thought it would be nice to write it down for other people with a similar issue. I know, this answer isn't great (I think it's my first time writing one), but it's better than nothing at all.